# Using a pipe to communicate between 2 different python scripts

Tags: python, pipe, ipc

I need to send some data from 1 python script to another, these 2 will be running on 2 different shells on the same machine. I was thinking of using pipe as the IPC mechanism. However I am not sure how to implement this.

script1.py : this script will read the values sent from script2

```
IPC_FIFO_NAME_A = "pipe_a"
try:
    os.mkfifo(IPC_FIFO_NAME_A)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise   
    # time.sleep might help here
    pass
fifo_a = os.open(IPC_FIFO_NAME_A, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
while 1:
    x = os.read(fifo_a, 1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
```

script2.py

This script needs to send values to script1 through pipe_a. How should I implement this script?

Not sure how to implement the script2